# Add random alphanumeric every nth character of String in swift

Tags: swift

I'm trying to make a simple encryption by adding a random alphanumeric character to a String after every 3rd character. With the help of Stackoverflow I could add the same character, but not a random one.

```
var code = "1234567890"

func randomAlphanumeric() -> String {
let alphanumeric = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
    return String((0..<1).map{ _ in alphanumeric.randomElement()! })
}

func encrypt(_ code: String, by separator: String = randomAlphanumeric(), stride: Int = 3) -> String {
    return code.enumerated().map { $0.isMultiple(of: stride) && ($0 != 0) ? "\(separator)\($1)" : String($1) }.joined()
    }

encrypt(code)
```

Anybody can help me how to call the randomAlphanumeric() every 4th time?

The result should be something like this:

```
let encryptedCode = "123A456z789i0"
```

Comment: Sure, because you are only calling randomAlphanumeric() once. You need to call it every 4th character.

Comment: Yes, I know. That's why I tried it with a for loop as well, but unfortunately without success, because the array became bigger each iteration.

Comment: Well if you know, what’s the question?

Comment: How to call the randomAlphanumeric() every 4th character. I edited the question to make it more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var code = "1234567890"

func randomAlphanumeric() -> String {
    let alphanumeric = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
    return String(alphanumeric.randomElement()!)
}

func encrypt(_ code: String, stride: Int = 3) -> String {
    
    // Array so we can insert new elements to it.
    // When we are done we can rejoin everything together
    var codeArray = code.map { String($0) }
    // The count of extra strings that will be added to the code.
    let extraStringsCount = code.count / stride
    // Add the extra strings to the array
    (0..<extraStringsCount).forEach { index in
        let indexToBeAddedTo = (stride + 1) * (index + 1) - 1
        let randomString = randomAlphanumeric()
        codeArray.insert(randomString, at: indexToBeAddedTo)
    }
    
    // rejoin the array and return
    return codeArray.joined()
}

encrypt(code)
// Prints something like "123J456Y789z0" which is what you want.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce` on a String iterator to form the string

```
func encrypt(_ code: String, stride: Int = 3) -> String {
    guard code.count > stride else { return code }

    return code.enumerated().reduce(into: "") {
        $0.append($1.element)
        if ($1.offset + 1) % stride == 0 { $0 += randomAlphanumeric() }
    }
}
```

Here is a variant that uses the same selection of characters but shuffles them in random order into an array that is kept locally. The difference is that any character will not be used more than once in the encryption

```
func encrypt(_ code: String, stride: Int = 3) -> String {
    guard code.count > stride else { return code }

    var random: [Character] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789".shuffled()

    return code.enumerated().reduce(into: "") {
        $0.append($1.element)
        if ($1.offset + 1) % stride == 0 { $0.append(random.popLast() ?? Character("")) }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, works fine as well. Just a (few) level too high for me, so it's hard to edit